# Need Help in understanding bootloader sequence

Tags: arm, bootloader, u-boot

I am going through stage-1 boot loader. I have a few doubts regarding that. First of all the boot sequence after reset is as follows:

1. Set the CPU to Supervisor Mode
2. Invalidate L1 Instruction,Data Cache and Translation Look aside
   Buffer (Tightly Coupled Memory if any)
3. Disable MMU and cache
4. Set up Stack size
5. Enable Instruction and Data cache as well as MMU

followed initial clock configuration and setting clock for Nand Flash Controller.

My question here is

1. We are already invalidating L1 Instruction/Data cache and TLB (Which is a part of MMU) but why do we need to disable the MMU and cache once again.

Please help in understanding it. Also please provide any links which make understand the boot sequence much better.

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Which stage 1 bootloader? The CPU itself boots with the MMU and cache off.

Answer (score 0):

The MMU will be disabled at boot, so step 3 looks redundant at first. Based on the limited information I will try to justify the logic:

At the end of the primary bootloader execution, code would jump to a secondary bootloader. If the secondary bootloader is not supplied or if the secondary bootloader messes up something before a new exception vector is setup; if an instruction to the effect mov pc,#0 (jump to null function pointer)occurs; then the primary bootloader will restart from step 1.

The caches may be corrupt, the MMU may be on, there are no guesses at this point. So if the bootloader has to start clean now, it will need to do steps 1 - 3 to make sure the environment is clean to execute. This looks like a precautionary measure more than a necessary one.

Bootloaders vary a lot in functionality and architecture. There is no real standardized way to do this. So the only real option would be to read code and ask questions.